# Script to import data from Excel file to SQL Server but the problem is it creates new data

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I created a Python script using Pandas which import data to SQL Server but the problem is that when I run the script it creates the new data in the table and I want to rewrite(override) the old data not to create more is there any way I can do it.

#File reading and main function

```
filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=['SR_NO','NTN'], sheet_name=None)

d = {}
for k, v in dfs.items():
    d[k] = pd.concat(df for df in dfs.values()).to_numpy().tolist()
print (d.keys())
```

#Writing data in SQL:

```
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, d[k])
    cursor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

`insert` will always create new data.

If you want to overwrite old data, you need to use `update` instead, and also match a single record to update, preferably with a primary key.

Of course, update will fail if there is not a matching record.  Perhaps you want `update or insert`

Comment: Or `merge`.....